# How to access body of request made with nodejs http library

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

I'm trying to make a post request passing json data. When the request arrives on my express server, it does not have a body. What am I doing wrong?

```
const http = require('http');
const req = http.request({
         hostname: 'localhost',
         port: 8080,
         path: '/',
         method: 'POST'
        }, (res) => {

    res.on('end', () => {
        // 
    });
});

req.write(JSON.stringify({ something: 'something' }));

req.end();
```

---

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body); // undefined
    res.send();
});

app.listen(8080);
```

I have to use the http library of nodejs.

Comment: Make sure you set `application/json` in header `Content-Type` of the request, also you have to move up your `ap.use(express.json())` middleware to the router handler so that It can parse before you capture the body.

Comment: Please don't edit questions to invalidate answers. Accept answers that solve the problem instead.

Comment: You have an error on line 7 where you are making an request remove `;` after `Post}`. Make the request and check the console it will work. If it doesn't please post your actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should:

- Move the line where you register the JSON parsing middleware so it appears **before** the line where you register the `/` handler. Handlers are called in order so with your current approach, the `/` will fire and end the chain without reaching the middleware.
- Add a `Content-Type: application/json` **request** header to the client-side code so that the body parser will not skip over it because it doesn't recognise the (un)declared data type.

Answer (score 0):

8bitIcon could be right. This behavior could be the result of not using a middle ware that parses the body of your request. Check out this [post](https://medium.com/@mmajdanski/express-body-parser-and-why-may-not-need-it-335803cd048c), might help you to solve the problem.

Thank you.